# (C++) How to round decimals like 1.05000?

Tags: decimal, rounding

I have a problem where in my algorhithm I should round the result down to 5 decimal places, with the zeros included even after the last number.

The only test-case not working in my algorhithm is:

> **Input**:
>
> milk 1
>    4
>    bread
>    meat
>    milk
>    aaaaa
>
> **Output**:
>
> 1.05000 // and my output displays 1.5

For an example; my result of **1.05** should display as **1.05000** or 1.2 as 1.20000. Now, the rest of the algorhithm is working fine, so the only problem is the rounding part:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {

 char name[50];
 cin >> name;
 double price = 0;
 cin >> price;
 int N;
 cin >> N;
 char check_name[50];
 double result = 0;
 bool found = false;
 double result_circle = 0;
 int finally_found = 0

 for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
    cin >> check_name;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
        if (name[i] == check_name[i]) {
            found = true;
        } else {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) {
        finally_found++;
        break;
    }
 }

 if (finally_found > 0) {
    result = price + (price * 0.05);
 } else {
    result = price + (price * 0.18);
 }

 // here is where the problem starts

 result_circle = result * 1000000; //temporarily expanding the number to the 6th decimal place
 if ((int)result_circle % 10 > 4) { // checking if the 6th decimal place is bigger than 4
    result_circle += 10; // increasing the 5th decimal place
 }

 result_circle = (int)result_circle / 10; // removing the 6th decimal place which we were checking

 cout << (int)result_circle / 100000 << '.' << (int)result_circle % 100000; // here is the main problem, where 105000 % 100000 is seen as 5000 not 05000

    return 0;
 }
```

*I assume the main problem here is that ‘105000 % 100000 = 5000’ because the 0 after the decimal point is unfortunately left out.*

If anyone could display the simplest way to fix this problem it would be great.

Comment: See e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision

Comment: @Bob__ setprecision didn’t fix my problem with the 0s. I think it gave me an output of -1.05 instead of 1.05000.

Comment: Try `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(5) << 1.05 << ' ' << 1.2 << '\n';`. Then, just for you to be warned, also try `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(55) << 1.05 << '\n' << 1.2 << '\n';`.

Comment: If you want to use only integers: `size_t n = 105000; std::cout << n / 100000 << '.' << std::setw(5) << std::setfill('0') << n % 100000 << '\n';`.

Comment: Bob__ thanks, it passed all of the test-cases, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iomanip> 
 .
 .
 .
cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << result;
```

This is the code that worked for me, answered by _Bob.

The full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char name[50];
    cin >> name;
    double price = 0;
    cin >> price;
    int N;
    cin >> N;
    char check_name[50];
    double result = 0;
    bool found = false;
    double result_circle = 0;
    int finally_found = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        cin >> check_name;
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(name); i++) {
            if (name[i] == check_name[i]) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (found) {
        finally_found++;
    }
}

if (finally_found > 0) {
    result = price + (price * 0.05);
} else {
    result = price + (price * 0.18);
}

cout << fixed << setprecision(5) << result;

return 0;
}
```